# How should I test the result of an SQLAlchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

Given the following table:

```
class Table(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
```

What is the best way of testing `result` from below:

```
result = session.query(Table)
```

Should I convert to a dictionary and compare against a dictionary fixture?

Comment: are you trying to test the `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` object? Or are you trying to test the results of something like a `.select().fetchall())`

Comment: I'd like to test the results. Basically I've built some delete and update queries that I'd like to test the results of after they've run.

Comment: you'll have to create a mock db, query it and check the result